# How do I loop multiple view controllers for an IOS iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, loops, uiviewcontroller, superview

I have a app with a main viewcontroller that loads a "first page" viewcontroller. once the user has clicked a few buttons, I exchange the "first page: view controller for the second this way:

```
        [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:self.secondPageVC.view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:^(BOOL done ) {
            [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        }];
```

In order to do this I include the header file of the "next page" that is going to load and create a instance of that next page in the class of the current View controller.

All of this works fine until i get to the last page. One of the button combinations sends the user back to the first page. However when I try to include the header file of the first page in the last page, I get errors.    What I think is happening is that each view controller class has an instance of the next page within its definition and when we get to the last page, adding an instance of the first page causes a loop that the compiler does not like. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? If I am not supposed to use view controllers like this, how should I set up a game that has 10 pages that can loop back to the first page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Including in your .m instead of in your .h will solve your problem
2. Look at UINavigationController

Comment: I would add that if you need to refer to the first vc in the header file, you can use a forward class declaration in your header...@class FirstViewController.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about the "forward class declaration". I read up on it and was able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> What I think is happening is that each view controller class has an
>   instance of the next page within its definition and when we get to the
>   last page, adding an instance of the first page causes a loop that the
>   compiler does not like.

I don't think that's it. In Objective-C, objects can't be *contained* in other objects, only *referred to* by other objects. That is, you never store an entire object in a variable, you only store a *pointer* to an object in a variable, so an object can't contain another object in the sense that an object in C++ can contain another object.

I'm not exactly sure what's going on with your code since you haven't shown us either the code or the errors, but here's how you can have several view controllers refer to each other:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property MyViewController *next;

@end


// ...somewhere in your code...

MyViewController *vc1 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:... bundle:...];
MyViewController *vc2 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:... bundle:...];
MyViewController *vc3 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:... bundle:...];

vc1.next = vc2;
vc2.next = vc3;
vc3.next = vc1;
```

Now, I'm using three view controllers of exactly the same type here just to keep the code short, but you don't have to do that. They don't even necessarily all have to use the same name for the `next` property. I *would* encourage you to avoid dependencies between view controllers if you can -- does each of your view controller classes *really* need to know what type the next one is? Your code will be easier to manage if they don't, so that you can easily change the order of the controllers if you want to.